# How do you print network history using _winreg in Python?

Tags: python, registry, winreg

I'm trying to print out the network history saved in the Windows Registry and am running into a snag.

I have two functions.  One to convert the binary text, and the second to get the actual data.

Here is what I have:

```
def val2addr(val):
    addr = ""
    for ch in val:
        addr += ("%02x "% ord(ch))
    addr = addr.strip(" ").replace(" ", ":")[0:17]
    return addr

def printNets():
    net = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged"
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, net)
    print key
    print '\n[*] Networks You have Joined.'
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            guid = EnumKey(key, i)
            netKey = OpenKey(key, str(guid))
            (n, addr, t) = EnumValue(netKey, 5)
            macAddr = val2addr(addr)
            netName = str(name)
            print '[+] ' + netName + ' ' + macAddr
            CloseKey(netKey)
        except:
            break
```

I believe the error is in this guid value:

```
for i in range(100):
    try:
        guid = EnumKey(key, i)
        netKey = OpenKey(key, str(guid))
        (n, addr, t) = EnumValue(netKey, 5)
```

When I run the "try" subcode by itself it throws up a:

> [ERROR 259] no more data available

pointing to the guid value.

I think that is where I am stuck.  I'm having trouble finding the error because it just gets thrown to the except code, and thus not giving me any feedback.

Please help!!!

EDIT: From what I am digging up it may be due to running 32bit Python on a 64bit system.  Still digging though.

Answer (score 1):

When I came across the 32/64 bit problem I got round it by using code similar to this

```
import winreg
HKLM =winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
bb = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged"
abc = winreg.OpenKeyEx(HKLM, bb,0,(winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY + winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS))
efg = winreg.EnumKey(abc,0)
z = winreg.OpenKeyEx(abc,str(efg))
q = winreg.QueryValueEx(z,"Description")[0]
print (q)
q = winreg.QueryValueEx(z,"DefaultGatewayMac")[0]
print (q)
```

Hope this helps pointing you in the right direction